# p5.js Add elements to canvas that are not affected by scale() function

Tags: javascript, scale, absolute, p5.js

I am creating a p5.js agar.io style game. In my draw function, I am using the [scale](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/scale) function to zoom-out of the map as my agar.io `blob` object's radius increases in size.

```
function draw() {
    var newzoom = 64 / blob.r;
    zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.1);
    scale(zoom);
    ...
    show_highscores();

 }
```

In my `draw()` function I am also drawing a label with my `show_highscores()` function, which I will be using to display the highscores of all of the players in the game.

```
function show_highscores() {
    textSize(12);
    text("Leaderboard", blob.pos.x - 150, blob.pos.y - 80);
    fill(0, 102, 153);
 }
```

***The Problem:***
My highscores label is changing position and size, relative to my blob (which is always in the middle of the screen) due to the `scale()` that I am running in my `draw()` function.

***The Question:***

Is there a way to draw my highscores label in a way that isn't affected by the [scale](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/scale) function. Is it possible to overlay a label on top of your canvas, or perhaps draw an additional canvas for my highscores label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [push()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and [pop()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) functions to revert to the base scale when needed before drawing the score card. Something like this:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  frameRate(1);
}

function draw(){
  background(50);
  fill('white');
  stroke(255);

  push();
  scale(random(0.2,3));
  rect(30, 20, 50, 50);
  line(0, 0, 100, 200);
  pop();
  
  stroke(0);
  fill(255, 0, 0, 100);
  rect(30, 20, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, this worked. I had to do pop(); then show_highscores(); and finally push(); to add my transformation changes back

Comment: Good stuff! Glad to help.